# Mapping an array of hashes to a keyed hash in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes that looks like this:

```
   array= [
      {
        "id"=> 101,
        "first_name"=> "xxx",
        "last_name"=> "G",
        "email"=> "xxx@yyyy.com",
        "phone_number"=> "555-555-5555"
      },
      {
        "id"=> 102,
        "first_name"=> "Jen",
        "last_name"=> "P",
        "email"=> "jen.p@example.com",
        "phone_number"=> "555-555-5555"
      }
    ]
```

I want to convert it to a hash that looks like this:

```
   array = {
          "101"=> 
          {
            "first_name"=> "xxx",
            "last_name"=> "G",
            "email"=> "xxx@yyyy.com",
            "phone_number"=> "555-555-5555"
          },
          "102"=>
          {
            "first_name"=> "Jen",
            "last_name"=> "P",
            "email"=> "jen.p@example.com",
            "phone_number"=> "555-555-5555"
          }
       }
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
    array.each do |a|
      a.map{|x| x[:id]}
    end
```

How can I do this in Ruby? I am looking at the map function, but not sure how to implement it in this case. Please help!

Comment: anyway, your array of hashes have the wrong syntax, it's not a Ruby hash, it's looks like javascript `json`

Comment: @Зелёный Okay thanks for pointing out. I am using the json library to convert this to a ruby hash. but my question still remains

Comment: @Зелёный please see edits

Comment: This is very similar to the output of `group_by` as in `array.group_by{|a| a[:id]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works(desctructive):

```
>> Hash[array.map { |x| [x.delete("id"), x] }]
=>{
    101=>{
        "first_name"=>"xxx",
        "last_name"=>"G",
        "email"=>"xxx@yyyy.com",
        "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"
    },
    102=>{
        "first_name"=>"Jen",
        "last_name"=>"P",
        "email"=>"jen.p@example.com",
        "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really return what the OP asked. It returns another Array of hashes, and it just wraps each original hash into a further hash. Other users have provided the right solution.

Comment: Since Ruby 2.1 it is also possible to use `x.to_h` instead of `Hash[x]`. Mostly aesthetic difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
array_h = Hash.new
array.each{|a| array_h[a["id"]] = a.reject{|e| e=='id' }}

#Output of array_h:
{
  101=>
    {
      "first_name"=>"xxx", 
      "last_name"=>"G", 
      "email"=>"xxx@yyyy.com", 
      "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"
    }, 
  102=>
    {
      "first_name"=>"Jen", 
      "last_name"=>"P", 
      "email"=>"jen.p@example.com", 
      "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will not modify your original Array.

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive variant (preserves `array`) while removing `"id"`:

```
{}.tap { |h| array.each { |a| nh = a.dup; h[nh.delete('id')] = nh } }
# => {101=>{"first_name"=>"xxx", "last_name"=>"G", "email"=>"xxx@yyyy.com", "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"}, 102=>{"first_name"=>"Jen", "last_name"=>"P", "email"=>"jen.p@example.com", "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"}} 
array
# => [{"id"=>101, "first_name"=>"xxx", "last_name"=>"G", "email"=>"xxx@yyyy.com", "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"}, {"id"=>102, "first_name"=>"Jen", "last_name"=>"P", "email"=>"jen.p@example.com", "phone_number"=>"555-555-5555"}]
```